# Unable to get authorization code Google Assistant for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: google, sdk

I am trying to install the Google Assistant with voice command on at least one of my computers. I started with the Raspberry Pi 3 last night. The install was smooth all the way up to getting an authorization code. After several hours of searching for a solution to my problem, I decided I would try to install the Google Assistant on my desktop. I've got the same result on my Raspberry Pi 3 (stretch operating system). As my desktop running Ubuntu 16.04, so I figure there is something I'm missing in the setup and or configuration prior to entering the command that generates the link.

I am following the instructions provided by Google (link below).

[Configure and Test the Audio - 
Google Assistant SDK | developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/audio?hardware=ubuntu)

The packages and files install smoothly. I get the URl generated to get an authorization code. The instruction is as follows -

"Copy the URL and paste it into a browser (this can be done on any machine). The page will ask you to sign in to your Google account. Sign into the Google account that created the developer project in the previous step."

The link takes me to an error 400 page (see screen shot).

[image: screen-shot of error page]

Little Help?

Comment: I get a 500, also on Ubuntu